# how to trigger an event on onload of <textarea>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my application there are few `<textarea>` presents and applied pagination to all these `<textarea>`. On a page one `<textarea>` is displayed.

Assume there are 10 `<textarea>` exist, then there will be exist 10 pages, one `<textarea>` on each page.

I have applied auto fit feature to these `<textarea>`, written below function for this :

```
function resizeTextarea(id) {

    var minHeight = "75px"; 
    textareaObj = document.getElementById(id);

    var scrollH = textareaObj.scrollHeight+'px';
    if((textareaObj.style.height != scrollH) && (textareaObj.scrollHeight!=0)){
       textareaObj.style.height = scrollH;
    } else
    {
       textareaObj.style.height = minHeight;
    }
}
```

I have called this function on some events in `<textarea>` element defination i.e. :

```
<textarea class="autoGrow" onkeyup="resizeTextarea(this.id);" onchange="resizeTextarea(this.id);" onkeydown="resizeTextarea(this.id);" onmouseup="resizeTextarea(this.id);" onfocus="resizeTextarea(this.id);" style="width:78%;height:75px;overflow:hidden" onclick="resizeTextarea(this.id);" rows="6" cols ="80" id="input"><?php echo decodeChars($textdata) ;?></textarea>
```

Auto fit feature works properly once user triggers above mentioned events, i.e. onchange,onkeyup,onkeydown.

I stuck to one main problem that, **auto fit feature wont work once page get's load.**

for this I have also added below code on document.ready i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       if($('.autoGrow')) {
         var setOfElement = $('.autoGrow');
         for(var i = 1 ; i <= setOfElement.length ; i++) {
            resizeTextarea(setOfElement[i].id);
          }
    } 
});
```

Still facing same problem that, user explicitly needs to click or jumps to `<textarea>` to work my auto fit feature.

Please folks suggest me any pointers you have.

Your sugggestion will helps me lot.

Thanks

-Pravin

Comment: what do you mean exact with "pagination"? Will there new documents get loaded or do you hide/show something(witch might have the same effect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could (with most of your current code so the calculations are the same) re-write it as a plugin, like this:

```
jQuery.fn.resizeTextarea = function(min) {
  min = min || 75; 
  return this.bind("keyup change click focus", function() {
    var sh = this.scrollHeight;
    $(this).height(function(i, h) {
       return h <= sh && sh != 0 ? sh : min;
    });    
  }).trigger("keyup"); //run it once immediately
};
```

Then in your `document.ready` handler, just call that on the elements you want, for example:

```
$(function() {
  $('.autoGrow').resizeTextarea();
  //or, as it's written you can pass a different minimum height, for example:
  //$('.autoGrow').resizeTextarea(45);  
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/DhRHA/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ll check that, bt is this function will trigger on page onload ? I am not so confident. User dont need to trigger specific events which I mentioned above ?

Comment: @pravin - That's what the `.trigger()` portion is for (or just `.keyup()` for the short version), it'll trigger the event handler it just bound, causing a resize immediately when the plugin is run as well.

Comment: i took the liberty of amending the bind method to include 'drop' in case drag/drop items were added. return this.bind("keyup change click focus drop" - http://jsfiddle.net/S37mX/

Answer (score 3):

Best solution ive found is this,

```
    function textAreaAdjust(o) 
    {
        o.style.height = "1px";
        o.style.height = (25+o.scrollHeight)+"px";
    }
```

Then in the input tag make the text area auto focus and call the javascript onfocus, took me ages to think of using autofocus, without it this will only work when the textarea is clicked on.

```
<textarea autofocus="true" onfocus="textAreaAdjust(this);"></textarea>
```

Comment: this is the best. autofocus="true"

Answer (score 0):

I'd trigger the functions after 2/3 seconds, so that the function get triggered after the page is loaded  :

```
setTimeout('yourFunctionThatResizesEverything()', 2)
```

Or you can add a script tag at the uppermost end of your page (but that's no good for w3c compliance), everything will be loaded before, and your textarea will be resized :

```
<script>
/*call your magical function*/
yourFunctionThatResizesEverything()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't the `for` loop be

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < setOfElement.length ; i++) { 
            resizeTextarea(setOfElement[i].id); 
          }
```

see **`for (var i=0`** instead of **`for(var i=1`**
Arrays start at 0 right? I am not very good at JQuery, but this is my first thought...

Comment: Yeah I hv modified my sample code snippet from < to <= . I think it's good now.